# Allowing Users to Keep Typing in the Single TextFormfield

Tags: flutter, size, textformfield

I am facing a problem. When a user is typing the title, it's ok until the length of the characters is shorter than the length of the textformfield (see Screenshot 1). However, if the length of the characters goes over the length of the textformfield, it seems the textformfield turns to 2 lines. I want to keep the single line but allow users to keep typing without the problem. How can I do this?

Thanks,

```
                          Container(
                            height: 45,
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    child: TextFormField(
                                      controller: _titleTextField,
                                      focusNode: _titleTextFieldFocusNode,
                                      keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                                      textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                                      maxLines: 1,
                                      maxLength: null,
                                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                                        labelText: 'Title',
                                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                              Radius.circular(3)),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  flex: 1,
                                )
                              ],
                            )),
```

[image: Typed as the length of the formtextfield]

[image: Typed more 1 character than the length of the formtextfield]

Comment: Increase the height of the container

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the one line TextFormField you can adjust the padding of what is inside of the field, the problem is that even though you are telling flutter you only want one line, the text is trying to move up.

Do some thing like this to adjust the padding and keep it centered

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
       contentPadding:
              const EdgeInsets.only(
              bottom: 5.0,
              top: 5.0)),
       labelText: 'Title',
       border: OutlineInputBorder(
           borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
               Radius.circular(3)),
               ),
           ),
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But That's not what meant. That isn't caused by padding but once the number of the characters goes over the counts, it goes to the next line.